# Detect if a F# key is mapped on VIM

Tags: vim, dictionary

How can I view/list only the `<F#>` keys with `:map`? I need to know what `<F#>` is doing... Newbie here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entering the following will list function key mappings for  to :

```
:for i in range(1, 12) | execute("map <F".i.">") | endfor
```

If you add a "verbose", you will be told where the key mappings were defined:

```
:for i in range(1, 12) | execute("verbose map <F".i.">") | endfor
```

If you have more than 12 function keys, adjust the second parameter of the "range()" expression accordingly.

Comment: Strange, why do you use `execute()`? With this variant it pretends to be a function while it really is not what is confusing for people with less vim knowledge.

Comment: Note that F1 has a default mapping which is not listed via this method (see `:h <F1>`). If someone knows other default mappings of functions keys I would be interested in getting to know them.

Answer (score 2):

you can just write

```
:map <F1>
```

to find out what the key  is mapped to. I other mappings like the ones that
start with `\` you can type

```
:map \
```

and vim will list all mappings starting with `\` for for the function keys I think you have to check them individually.

Answer (score 2):

`:map` (without arguments) shows all the maps available for *n*, *v* and *o*
modes. For the other modes, try the correspondent command (for example `:imap`
for insert mode).

Now it's just a matter of skimming the output looking for function key maps.
If you give the command a specific key:

```
:nmap <F4>
```

That map will be presented.

Answer (score 0):

To Extend Jeets solution by mapping it in your .vimrc .

I'm always changing the configuration of my Function Keys so it's really useful to be able to remind myself what's there.

Just type ,f in normal mode to list the Function keys F1-F12

```
:nnoremap ,f :for i in range(1, 12) <bar> execute("map <F".i.">") <bar> endfor
```